# Do I need to worry about RESTORE FILELISTONLY types other than L and D?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx, there are four types, `L`, `D`, `F` and `S`.

All of the actual database instances I've seen so far (SQL Server 2008 and up) only have types `L` and `D`. I've written a script to backup and restore databases very quickly (there are a wealth of answers on Stack Overflow with instructions) but I'm wondering if I'll ever need to worry about the other two types: `F` and `S`.

I've read that full-text catalogues (`F`) are virtual from SQL Server 2008 onwards, so it seems like I will never encounter those. The documentation says that `S` can be an in-memory OLTP container, but I'm not sure if FileStream and FileTable are also virtual or not.

Answer (score 0):

> In SQL Server, the full-text catalog is a logical concept and does not reside in a filegroup. Therefore, to back up a full-text catalog in SQL Server, you must identify every filegroup that contains a full-text index that belongs to the catalog. Then you must back up those filegroups, one by one.
>
> When a full-text index is created, it is placed in one of the following locations:
> A user-specified filegroup.
> The same filegroup as base table or view, for a nonpartitioned table.
> The primary filegroup, for a partitioned table.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142511.aspx)

If the database has full text catalog,  you'll need to backup the filegroups pertaining to it. It is possible that there is a filegroup only containing the index for the full text catalog and nothing else, as seen by "A user-specified filegroup".

> If a full-text index resides in a separate filegroup from all of the associated table data, the behavior of piecemeal restore depends on which of the filegroups is restored and brought online first:

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190643(v=sql.105).aspx)

Now for filestream, you can see an example of backups and restores here:
[MSSQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1854/how-to-backup-and-restore-a-sql-server-filestream-enabled-database/)

You can see that the filestream backup data is classified as type S as you talked about. It is also seen in SQL as FILESTREAM type and is it's own file to be restored.

To recap, you may run into F and S type in the filelist. S type seems more likely as it's possible the full text indices reside in a filegroup with tables or other data and would be seen as D. You can specify your own filegroup for full text indices that contain just the indices however.